# Mismo nivel de dos elementos en linea con distinto tamaño de letra

Tags: css3

Tengo este html

`<header>`

`<div id='icono'>Canciones</div>`

`<ul>
    <li>Inicio</li>
    <li>Canciones</li>
</ul>`

y la letra de #icono es de 20px y la lista de 16px.¿Cómo podría hacer para que se quedará al mismo nivel al dar un alto al header? Lo he intentado con margin y padding pero no se queda bien.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a las cajas flexibles **{flex-box}** => https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Por cierto a mismo nivel te refieres a que estén alineados verticalmente?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con `padding` o `margin`, pero es conveniente que alinees verticalmente ambos arriba.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo:

```
<style>
header {height: 30px;}
#icono {font-size: 20px; padding-top: 12px;}
ul li {font-size: 16px;}
#icono, ul {display: inline-block; width: 30%; vertical-align: top;}
</style>

<header>
<div id="icono">Canciones</div>
<ul>
 <li>Inicio</li>
 <li>Canciones</li>
</ul>
</header>
```

Puedes ver cómo queda [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/hg9amskp/).

Comment: al final lo consegí con line-height

Comment: @BorjaSanchez Contesta a tu propia pregunta con la solución para que pueda ayudar a futuros lectores.